# How to make a click with a mouse to a specific position on a mac?

Tags: click, osx-mountain-lion, automator

Given dynamic (meaning those could change in time) x, y coordinate values of your screen how to make an actual click programmatically on that point (or via automator, or anything else for that matter) on a mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found two neat solutions to this problem:

1. is a command line utility called [Cliclick](http://www.bluem.net/en/mac/cliclick/)
2. is a pretty neat IDE and a bonus scripting language called [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org)

Comment: unfortunately sikuli requires you to click a GUI popup asking for COMMAND LINE OPTIONS of all things before the script can run. At least that's where I'm stuck. Believe it or not, I'm looking for a program that can click the sikuli "OK" button to move past the GUI-COMMAND-LINE-OPTIONS-PROMPT. (sorry, a little irritated)

Comment: cliclick works. can use mac's cropped screenshot command to grab the coordinates easily. swag.

Comment: cliclick is the tool to go. If you're too lazy to manually copy the coordinates from mac's cropped screenshot you can go with "cliclick p". If you need a series of clicks, you can use mousecabs/mouserep (https://github.com/wolframteetz/mousecabs/) to automatically capture mouse click coordinates and write a cliclick script for you - if you're not afraid to edit a printf statement and recompile mouserep.

Answer (score 0):

[Cliclick](http://www.bluem.net/en/mac/cliclick/) with loop:

```
$ for ((i=0; i<=60; i++)); do cliclick -r w:1000 c:297,256 c:381,255; done
```

Comment: Thanks for the loop tip. Do you have an idea how to get the current current Mouse Position in a shell script?

Comment: From `cliclick -h` ---


```p[:str] Will PRINT the given string. If the string is “.”, the
          current MOUSE POSITION is printed. As a convenience, you can skip
          the string completely and just write “p” to get the current position.
          Example: “p:.” or “p” will print the current mouse position
          Example: “p:'Hello world'” will print “Hello world”
```

Comment: i know, but how do i get it a shell scipt an save it in a variable. Sorry the previous question was to vague.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but I wanted to post an answer just in case anybody stumbles upon this.

There's a new completely platform independent automation language called [javAuto](http://javauto.org). It's pretty much a java program the can compile and run your code cross platform.

The syntax is almost exactly like the popular automation language AutoIT.

For simulating a mouse click you can use this command:

```
mouseClick(button, x, y);
```

Example:

```
//click in the center of the screen
mouseClick("left", SCREEN_WIDTH/2, SCREEN_HEIGHT/2 );
```